# Database Initialisation issue with EF5 and Simple Membership

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, simplemembership

I have a two database initialisers in my global.asax file.

One, which should create my database with the relevant tables, and the second which initialises all the tables needed for simple membership.

The problem i'm having is that the first initialization method which should create my DB, doesn't do anything (at least it seems that way). The simple membership initialiser works fine.

The tables that i want to be created from my context only gets created when a new instance of the context is created within my repository class. This then fails because it's trying to create a user profile table that already exists because the `WebSecurity.InitialiseDatabaseConnection` initializer already created it?

Any Ideas of why the first Database initialiser is not being executed until the context is created in the repository method?

The database is a SQL Server LocalDB.

Here's my `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>());
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyDb", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
}
```

Here's the Context class:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("name=MyDb")
    {


    }

    public DbSet<MyEntity> myEntity{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

}
```

And here's the repository method:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{

    var user = _userRepository.GetUserByUserName(userName);

    db.UserProfiles.Attach(user);

    if (rack.Id == 0)
    {
        rack.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
        rack.AddedBy = user;

        db.MyEntity.Attach(rack);
        db.Entry(rack).State = EntityState.Added;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        db.MyEntity.Attach(rack);
        db.Entry(rack).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**  I've moved the SimpleMembership initializer to the Seed Method of my Configuration class as below, and whilst this solves the problem of the tables being created in the right order i'm still none the wiser about why the database doesn't get initialised when the initialiser is called in the `Application_Start` method

```
protected override void Seed(RackTrackContext context)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyDb", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

        if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
            Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");

        if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("User1"))
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
                "User1",
                "CodeMonkey"
                );

        if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser("User1").Contains("Administrator"))
            Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "User1" }, new[] { "Administrator" });
    }
```

**Edit No2:**

In order to get it to work, i 've used created a new context in the Application_start method and retrieved a result from the db. This then applies the migrations at the stage that i want them to be applied.

It's messy, it's ugly, and won't win any awards, but hey it works and no animals were harmed while doing it, so in it goes.

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>());

        //this code is here to ensure that the context is created and migrations applied,
        //prior to the user seeing the start screen for the app. Must be a better way of doing it....
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var results = db.MyEntity.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

There's some Rep up for grabs if anyone can tell me a better way!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        var results = db.MyEntity.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

try

```
new MyContext().Database.Initialize(false)
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```